# why isn't my router redirecting - interactive map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, router

I have this interactive map where if you click on a certain country it redirects you to a page for that specific country but Redirect isn't working for me and I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. This is the code:

```
onClick={() => {
                    const {NAME} = geo.properties;
                    if(NAME == 'Bulgaria')
                      {
                        <Redirect to='pages/services' />
                      }
                  }}
```

This is the full code of the .js file for my interactive map:

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import {
  ComposableMap,
  Geographies,
  Geography
} from "react-simple-maps";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

...
const MapChart = ({ setTooltipContent }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ComposableMap data-tip="" projectionConfig={{ scale: 200 }}>

          <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
            {({ geographies }) =>
              geographies.map(geo => (
                <Geography
                  key={geo.rsmKey}
                  geography={geo}
                  onMouseEnter={() => {
                    const { NAME, POP_EST } = geo.properties;
                    setTooltipContent(`${NAME} — ${rounded(POP_EST)}`);
                  }}
                  onMouseLeave={() => {
                    setTooltipContent("");
                  }}
                  onClick={() => {
                    const { NAME } = geo.properties;
                    if (NAME === 'Bulgaria') {
                    this.setState({ redirect: true });
                    }
                  }}
                  ...
                />
              ))
            }
          </Geographies>
      </ComposableMap>
    </>
  );
};

export default memo(MapChart);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

This isn't how JSX works. It isn't redirecting because the function can't return renderable JSX nor does it try to navigate. Everything that is rendered needs to be in the `render` function, or functional component return. This handler doesn't return anything.

## Solution

You can either declaratively conditionally render a `Redirect` component, or imperatively issue a navigation action.

### Using a `Redirect` component on condition.

```
// later in render/return
if (redirect) {
  return <Redirect to='/pages/services' />;
}

return (
  ...

  onClick={() => {
    const { NAME } = geo.properties;
    if (NAME === 'Bulgaria') {
      setRedirect(true);
    }
  }}

  ...
);
```

MapChart

```
const MapChart = ({ setTooltipContent }) => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false); // <-- add redirect state

  return redirect ? ( // <-- conditional render redirect
    <Redirect to="/pages/services" />
  ) : (
    <ComposableMap data-tip="" projectionConfig={{ scale: 200 }}>
      <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
        {({ geographies }) =>
          geographies.map((geo) => (
            <Geography
              ...
              onClick={() => {
                const { NAME } = geo.properties;
                if (NAME === "Bulgaria") {
                  setRedirect(true); // <-- set redirect state
                }
              }}
              ...
            />
          ))
        }
      </Geographies>
    </ComposableMap>
  );
};
```

### Using `history.replace`.

```
onClick={() => {
  const { NAME } = geo.properties;
  if (NAME === 'Bulgaria') {
    history.replace('/pages/services');
  }
}};
```

MapChart

```
const MapChart = ({ history, setTooltipContent }) => { // <-- destructure history route prop
  return (
    <ComposableMap data-tip="" projectionConfig={{ scale: 200 }}>
      <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
        {({ geographies }) =>
          geographies.map((geo) => (
            <Geography
              ...
              onClick={() => {
                const { NAME } = geo.properties;
                if (NAME === "Bulgaria") {
                  history.replace("/pages/services"); // <-- imperative navigation
                }
              }}
              ...
            />
          ))
        }
      </Geographies>
    </ComposableMap>
  );
};
```

***Note:** If `MapChart` isn't directly rendered by a `Route` component (i.e. it doesn't receive the [route props](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props)) then you can use the [`useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) react hook.*

```
const history = useHistory();
```

And the navigation would be exactly the same from the click handler.

Comment: I apologize in advance for asking very dumb questions for this is the first time I work with JavaScript.

Where do I add the render function? I am quite frankly a bit lost.
I will add all of my code as an answer to my question

Comment: @Emiliya No worries. There wasn't enough context in your snippet to know if you were rendering a class-based or functional react component. Class-based components have a `render` lifecycle function whereas the entire function body of a functional component is considered the "render" function. I've updated my answer to reflect your functional component.

Comment: Thaaaank you so so so much, kind sir.